# How to disable smooth scrolling in WinSCP

Tags: scrolling, winscp

How to disable smooth scrolling in WinSCP? I would like to turn it off because:

- smooth scrolling doesn't work perfectly (it's slow, laggy)
- i don't like smooth scrolling

*(Note: i use Commander interface)*

My environment:

- Windows 10 20H2
- Winscp latest version

Comment: Are you using the lastest version ? What OS ? When and where exactly do you face the scrolling issue ?

Comment: I updated the question for environment details. Regarding the second question - this problem occurs when I scroll through the file list with the scroll bar.